# Programming pattern name that figures out which method to call from a response

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I've seen, and written, this style of code before and I know there's a name for it, but I can't remember. In JS you'd have a key/value pair of responses and what to do for that response. Something like:

```
// Some base class
Foo.extend({
  handleRequest: function () {
    // Make some XHR request
    makeRequest({
      onSuccess: function (response) {
        // will call acceptRequest if response.status is accept
        this[this._responders[response.status]]();
      }.bind(this);
    });
  },
  acceptRequest: function () {},
  denyRequest: function () {},
  _responders: {
    accept: "acceptRequest",
    deny: "denyRequest"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the limited information you provided, I'm going to guess you are describing the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), which allows you to select an algorithm's behavior at runtime.